# How do I show the current date & time in non-editable fields?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Today's Date</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
            </div>
            <input name="TodaysDate" type="text" class="form-control" data-inputmask="'alias': 'mm/dd/yyyy'" data-mask required>
        </div><!-- /.input group -->
    </div>
</div><!-- /.col -->

<div class="col-md-3">                                  
    <div class="bootstrap-timepicker">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Current Time</label>
            <div class="input-group">                                                
                <input name="CurrentTime" type="time" class="form-control" disabled>
                <div class="input-group-addon">
                    <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.input group -->
        </div><!-- /.form-group -->
    </div>
</div><!-- /.col -->
```

The above is the code I am working with. My question is, how do I, by default, make these display the current date & time? Here is how they are displayed on the screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7AAR.jpg (I will make the date field disabled once it pulls current date).

I want them to appear as text boxes, because I will make it where once submitted on the page, I will capture the current date & time in MongoDB. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current date and time with jQuery and then change the inner value of the element.
`$("input[name='maTodaysDaten']").val($.datepicker.formatDate('dd M yy', new Date()));
 $("input[name='mTodaysDatean']").val($.timepicker('setTime', new Date()));`

Answer (score 0):

You could use JQuery get the current Date/Time and set the Values of the fields. This way, it doesn't matter if the field is disabled:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var d = new Date();
  var month = d.getMonth()+1;
  var day = d.getDate();
  var hour = d.getHours();
  var minute = d.getMinutes();
  var second = d.getSeconds();
  var outputDate = d.getFullYear() + '/' + (month<10 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' + (day<10 ? '0' : '') + day;
  var outputTime = (hour<10 ? '0' : '') + hour + ':' + (minute<10 ? '0' : '') + minute + ':' + (second<10 ? '0' : '') + second;
  $('input[name=TodaysDate]').val(outputDate);
  $('input[name=CurrentTime]').val( "00:01:00" );
});
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a46u5dL8/) for you